# Some kind of push communication between Android -> iPhone without a server inbetween

Tags: iphone, android, push-notification

Im looking to initiate pushcommunication between Android and iPhone, both ways. The data that is to be transferred is critical so therefor I cannot use ordinary push because its not prioritzed.

It is important that the user doesnt "see" the communication.
I have looked at using SMS and "catch" the message before it reaches the ordinary "SMS application" of the phone. As I understand this is possible in Android but not in iPhone.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you don't use a server, how are the devices going to find each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Bonjour` (a.k.a. `Zeroconf`) for this.  There are tons of links for using Bonjour on the iPhone; here's a link for doing it on Android:

http://android.noisepages.com/2010/02/yes-android-can-do-zeroconfbonjour-jmdns/